# Pandas column of lists, append a new column to each list

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, numpy-ndarray

For example, I got a pd.Series of list like below

```
test = pd.Series([[1, 0, 0, 0],[0, 1, 0, 0],[0, 1, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0, 1],[1, 0, 0, 0]])
print(test)
0    [1, 0, 0, 0]
1    [0, 1, 0, 0]
2    [0, 1, 0, 0]
3    [0, 0, 0, 1]
4    [1, 0, 0, 0]
```

what I want to do is that, I want to add (the index + 1) of each element into the each list, like

```
0    [1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
1    [0, 1, 0, 0, 2]
2    [0, 1, 0, 0, 3]
3    [0, 0, 0, 1, 4]
4    [1, 0, 0, 0, 5]
```

how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using this `pd.Series` with a `list` comprehension:

```
import pandas as pd
test = pd.Series([[1, 0, 0, 0],[0, 1, 0, 0],[0, 1, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0, 1],[1, 0, 0, 0]])
print(test + pd.Series([[i + 1] for i in test.index]))
```

Output:

```
0    [1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
1    [0, 1, 0, 0, 2]
2    [0, 1, 0, 0, 3]
3    [0, 0, 0, 1, 4]
4    [1, 0, 0, 0, 5]
dtype: object
```

Comment: I vote up already, but seems that when I run "pd.Series([[i + 1] for i in test.index])", it returns an error of "TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable"

Comment: @NicolasH Try: `print(test + pd.Series([[i + 1] for i in test.index()]))`

Answer (score 2):

```
test = pd.Series([[1, 0, 0, 0],[0, 1, 0, 0],[0, 1, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 1],[1, 0, 0, 0]])
b=0
for a in test:
    b+=1
    a.append(b)
print(test)
```

will give

```
0    [1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
1    [0, 1, 0, 0, 2]
2    [0, 1, 0, 0, 3]
3    [0, 0, 0, 1, 4]
4    [1, 0, 0, 0, 5]
```

Answer (score 2):

#### [`np.column_stack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html)

Stack the index to the existing list assign back to test in-place:

```
test[:] = np.column_stack([test.tolist(), test.index + 1]).tolist()
test
 
0    [1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
1    [0, 1, 0, 0, 2]
2    [0, 1, 0, 0, 3]
3    [0, 0, 0, 1, 4]
4    [1, 0, 0, 0, 5]
dtype: object
```

Here, the Series is converted to a list of lists, then concatenated with (index + 1). When assigning back, you need to use a list of lists because pandas doesn't understand you want a column of lists if you're assigning a numpy array back.

---

#### [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) and [`itertools.count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count)

Another option, having fun with itertools:

```
from itertools import count

c = count(1)
test.map(lambda l: [*l, next(c)])

0    [1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
1    [0, 1, 0, 0, 2]
2    [0, 1, 0, 0, 3]
3    [0, 0, 0, 1, 4]
4    [1, 0, 0, 0, 5]
dtype: object
```